# Master SQL View

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am wanting to create a view using postgresql that essentially shows me all information in the entire database.

Example:

**Table 1**

- pin
- insert_time

**Table 2**

- tmr
- insert_time

**Table 3**

- weight
- insert_time

***Desired Output View***

- pin
- tmr
- weight
- insert_time

The output view would be sorted by insert_time. It would just leave the columns blank that aren't used for that row ie. If it pulled from Table 1 then PIN and insert_time would be filled but tmr and weight would be left blank.

How can I go about doing this? I can create other tables if needed, but not sure how I would do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW everything
AS
SELECT insert_time, pin, null as tmr, null as weight
FROM table_1
UNION ALL
SELECT insert_time, null as pin, tmr, null as weight
FROM table_2
UNION ALL
SELECT insert_time, pin, tmr, weight
FROM table_3;
```

Comment: That is perfect! Thanks for your fast response.